# How to avoid visual studio warning when using C# variable in the javascript section of a razor view

Tags: visual-studio, razor

In a razor view, I have a script snippet using the model property values:

```
<script>
var @(Model.DialogModel.DialogVar) = new AjaxDialog("@(Model.DialogModel.DialogHtmlId)");
</script>
```

Both DialogVar and DialogHtmlId are of type String and the script works fine, but visual studio shows there is an "Expected Identifier" error around the "=" sign.

How to suppress the error prompt without turning the "Show syntax errors" off globally?

Answer (score 0):

Put the entire line into a razor expression like:

```
var dlg = new AjaxDialog("@(Model.DialogModel.DialogHtmlId)");
@("var " + Model.DialogModel.DialogVar + " = dlg;")
```